# Can't Get Content - Give Me Ajax Error (js)

Tags: javascript, c#, json

This is how I try to send something to my javascript via json. Coming from Stripe to make payment to 3d (SCA)

Where the problem lies in the value coming from the strip API it tells me that it is "*value can't be null. Parameter name: input*" and it comes up when I only run it with js (ajax)

```
[HttpPost]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("Members/AddMembership/{id}/{CompaniesId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddMembership(MembersView model)
    {
        try
        {
            //more here....
            model.PiinVoice = subscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret;
            //more here....

            return Json(model.PiinVoice);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            TempData[TempDataClass.Error] = true;
            TempData[TempDataClass.ErrorMsg] = HelperText.ExceptionError + e.Message;
            //return RedirectToAction("", "User");

            return Json(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Members/AddMembership/' + Id + '/' + CompaniesId, //jump to httppost action,meet [Route("Members/AddMembership/{id}/{CompaniesId}")]
        dataType: "json",
        data: "",
        type: "Post",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {//receive response from httppost action
            //result is the response of the httppost action,you can handle it
            console.log("New: " + Id, CompaniesId);
            console.log(result.PiinVoice)
            //var paymentIntentSecret = document.getElementById('PiinVoice').value;
            //stripe.handleCardPayment(paymentIntentSecret).then(function (result) {
            //    if (result.error) {
            //        // Display error.message in your UI.
            //        // Inform the user if there was an error.
            //        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            //        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            //    } else {
            //        // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
            //        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            //    }
            //});
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr)
        }
    });
```

If I look at **result.PiinVoice** then it gives me **undefined** but if I just write result then it gives me "*Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input*"

So what I want to do with my question is: How can I get done so that the result I send via json comes into js which I can then use to work with to strip.

As the problem is right now it is that the value that is in my controller in no way comes across to my js ajax

Comment: Try debugging the code and see if you are getting data in your pinvoice

Comment: I have try to debug: https://imgur.com/EZP34K4  It's like it's like I can't afford to see what goes wrong. Maybe you can see why I can't debug js and controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in your ajax code change the code `console.log(result.PiinVoice)` to `console.log(result)`. You will notice you are sending `PiinVoice` as `result`.

Change your controller to return `Json(model);` instead of return `Json(model.PiinVoice);`

Comment: Okay, I get to fix my consol.log for results only and at the same time my json only for model. It's like this now. `model.PiinVoice = subscription.LatestInvoice.PaymentIntent.ClientSecret;
                return Json(model);` and `console.log(result)`